# Dúvida com data e hora no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Eu tenho um campo no banco do tipo “char”, estou retornando as datas desta forma:

```
select
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),HORA_FECHAMENTO) as HORA_FECHAMENTO,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(hour, +0, getdate()), 120) as HORA_ATUAL 
  from TB_ESTRACAO   
where IDEXTRACAO = 5
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como eu poderia trazer as duas datas iguais junto com o horário

Comment: Existe um problema na atual logica, hora_fechamento pode estar relacionado a qualquer dia

Comment: @itasouza: Não existe 24:00. De 23:59 passa para 0:00. No exemplo que postou, ou ficaria 2017-01-28 23:59:59 ou então 2017-01-29 0:00:00. Qual prefere?

Comment: Sugestão, não altere a pergunta assim, acrescente informações ao final dela, para não descaracterizar a pergunta inicial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei bem se é isso que procura, mas pode trabalhar desse modo:

`Schema` teste:

```
CREATE TABLE teste
    ([HORA] VARCHAR(20))
;

INSERT INTO teste
    ([HORA])
VALUES
    ('24:00'),
    ('10:00'),
    ('5:20')
;
```

---

```
SELECT
CONCAT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), getdate(),126),' ',HORA,':00') AS HORA_FECHAMENTO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(hour, +0, getdate()), 120) AS HORA_ATUAL 
FROM teste
```

Explicando a linha: `CONCAT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), getdate(),126),' ',HORA,':00')`
Pego somente a data no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` e concateno com a hora que esta no bd, junto com os segundos, que também não foram definidos.

Note que existem erros lógicos no seu bd, o ideal seria trabalhar as duas datas com o mesmo formato, `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, do jeito que esta você esta "forçando" o dia do fechamento para que seja o dia de hoje.

Veja funcionando no [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90e31/33/0)

---

[A função `concat` não é implementada no `sql-server 2008`](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/concat-function-in-sql-server/), como saída a solução pode ser:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), getdate(),126)+' '+HORA+':00') AS HORA_FECHAMENTO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(hour, +0, getdate()), 120) AS HORA_ATUAL 
FROM teste
```

Comment: eu fiz o seu exemplo e tive um erro: 
Mensagem 195, Nível 15, Estado 10, Linha 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: eu fiz a alteração, postei a resposta, veja que a data e hora fica tudo junto

Comment: postei o resultado do teste que fiz com o ajuste

Comment: Tudo certo, agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda!